# Nightmare then() invokes immediately after evaluate()

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, electron, es6-promise, nightmare

Consider the following code snippet:

```
nightmare
    .evaluate(function (resolve){
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(null, 1234);
        }, 1500)
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('SUCCESS', result);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log('ERROR', e);
    });
```

Assuming that `nightmare` instance has been initialized before, I have also used methods such as `goto()` and `inject()` (that part of code is very huge, but I can try cleaning it to present over there if necessary). But the result I get finally - is unlikely `SUCCESS   null` instead of `SUCCESS   1234`.

I was experimenting with that and have understood that if call `.wait(15000)` before `.evaluate()` in that chain (or setup a breakpoint after `.goto()` and before the `.evaluate()` and wait some time when it's fired), the code works as it's exactly expected to.

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: `resolve(null, 1234)` why do you pass *null* but expect *1234*?

Comment: Because, if according to the spec, the first argument is an erroneous result (instead of using `reject()`) to be passed to `catch()`. But I need `then()` function to be invocated, so, I pass `null` as the first argument. Although that doesn't actually matter. What really matters is the fact that `then()` hires *before* the setTimeout() finishes and calls `resolve()`.

Comment: You do not return anything. There is an example using Promises in the [documentation of `.evaluate`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2).

Comment: based on the documentation for nightmare - you're using `.evaluate` wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX, really? Copy-paste from the documentation: `If the arguments passed are one fewer than the arguments expected for the evaluated function, the evaluation will be passed a callback as the last parameter to the function.`. I should not return something because I am using `setTimeout()` function which resolves the Promise deferred (in 1500ms). If I will return something, it should affect nothing, because the callback function inside `evaluate()` has an extra-argument to resolve the nightmare promise.

Comment: Actaully, I can't see any examples in the documentation that pass `resolve` to the evaluate callback, the only close example in the documentation is like the code in the answer below

Comment: @JaromandaX You must be kidding. Follow [that link](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2), then press `Ctrl+F`, and copy&paste `If the arguments passed` . The code snippet below the highlighted paragraph you will see is exactly what you can't see...

Comment: Didn't ever mind that I'll come over StackOverflow to teach someone to search through the documentation. On my own question.....

Comment: The only difference between my code and the code from an official documentation is that I am using a native function definition instead of an arrow-function, and my arg-callback is called `resolve()` instead of `done()`.

Comment: and whatever `selector` is in the documented code, you've totally dropped from the argument list - again, the pattern you are using is not like any example in the documentation, it's subtle, and I really don't give that much of a damn to read the docs to understand nightmare for you ... if you think that argument names and arrow functions confused me, you are mistaken

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following answer,

```
nightmare
    .evaluate(function (){
       return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{        
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(1234);
        }, 1500)
       })
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('SUCCESS', result);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log('ERROR', e);
    });
```

What does it do? It returns a promise. So the code will wait until it's resolved.

Also, you must resolve 1234 if you want to get 1234, and not a `null`.

Learn more about promises,

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth